# javafx load fxml into pane

Tags: javafx, fxml, gridpane

Im trying to load fxml files into gridpane when init the parent controller. Each cell in gridpane will load the .fxml file. But i can't load the fxml file in init method.

There is my code

```
private GridPane gridDetailCollection;

public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    list.add("1");
    list.add("2");
    list.add("3");
    combo.setItems(list);

    System.out.println("detail collection");
    try{
        Node nodeItem1 = (Node)  FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/DetailCollectionItem.fxml"));

        Node nodeItem2 = (Node)  FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/DetailCollectionItem.fxml"));


        gridDetailCollection.add(nodeItem1,0,0);
        gridDetailCollection.add(nodeItem2,1,0);

    }catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

File DetailCollectionItem.fxml removed the "fx:controller"

Can anyone solve this problem? Thanks so much.

Comment: the same object can not be placed in several places at the same time.

Comment: I mean the problem is not about nodeItem. The problem is this line FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/DetailCollectionItem.fxml")) throws Exception. I edited the question

Comment: show full stack trace of exception

Comment: it just show this line " file:/C:/Users/Bao/Documents/NetBeansProjects/EnglishApp/target/EnglishApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/fxml/DetailCollectionScene.fxml "

Comment: replace `System.out.println(e.getMessage());` with `e.printStackTrace()`